# After I created an Azure Virtual Desktop session host, but users are unable to access a remote desktop

Tags: azure, session, azure-active-directory, remote-desktop, virtual-desktop

I created the following in Azure Virtual Desktop:

1.Host pool
2.Workspace
3.Application group
4.Session host VM (Domain joined using Azure Active Directory)
Then, I assigned the desired group to the application group.
I configured "targetisaadjoined:i:1" in the RDP properties.

However, I couldn't access it. I assigned some appropriate roles to the group, but users are unable to access the Remote Desktop `https://client.wvd.microsoft.com/webclient/v2/index.htm`l.

What am I missing.?

I need to find what I set some Roles or another setthings so that User can access Remote Desk Top Link and see session.

Answer (score 1):

Created an Azure Virtual Desktop host pool like below:

[image]

[image]

Host pool with 1 virtual machine and Application group like below:

[image]

Created Application group with default session Desktop.

[image]

***Make sure Application group -> under manage, Assignments -> Try to add users like below:***

You can add another application group and add application like Microsoft edge, team, excel ensure to add assignment.

[image]

Under host pool select your virtual machine check `Domainjoinedcheck` is success like below:

[image]

Now, when I tried to login to the user on InPrivate mode user able to login using web client remote desktop successfully like below:

[image]

To know more in detail, you can check this [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u99cY0MXZds)  by *Microsoft Mechanics*

Answer (score 0):

Select the resource group that contains the VM.

Select Access control (IAM).

Select Add > Add role assignment. Assign the following role:

- Role: Virtual Machine Administrator Login or Virtual Machine User Login
- Assign the Role to your Users, group, service principal, or managed identity